# VMWare equivalent of the UNIX server console

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I used to be a hardware support engineer for UNIX servers. At that time, it happened regularly that a server was that busy that it had become impossible to log in, so doing regular analysis was impossible.
I could, however, plug a cable into another entry, and use some kind of "console" (a command prompt), from where I still did have access to the machine, and from there, some basic analysis (like a `top` or a `df -hk` command) could still be done.

Now I'm giving software support in a company, where customers are using virtual Windows machines for running our software, and there has been the issue where the virtual machine was that much occupied that an RDP (remote desktop) was not possible anymore, so the customer has simply decided to restart the virtual machine, leaving me with no clue about what happened and, as a result, no possibility to avoid the issue from happening again.

In my opinion, there should be something similar than the hardware console of the UNIX servers, but I don't know the name of this feature, and I have no idea on how to configure it (is it possible to reserve some virtual machine's memory/CPU for this console and how to do this). In top of that, I don't even know what VM software the customer is using.

Does anybody know the name of the feature and if there's a way to configure this for the mostly used VM software packages (HyperV, vSphere, ...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most virtual machine software indeed have console access for guests; often it's how you install the guest OS in the first place. Usually it doesn't need any additional configuration. (By 'console' I mean the input/output that the VM considers to be hardwired display and keyboard.)

- In Hyper-V, the VM host's administrator can open *Hyper-V Manager* and double-click on any VM in the list to attach to the console. (In your case, cancel the "Enhanced session" prompt that shows up.)
- In VMware vSphere – I have no idea, but here's a link that says it's pretty much the same: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-92986CAA-4FDE-4AA0-A9E9-084FF9E03323.html
- In KVM/libvirt – same, open *virt-manager*, select the VM and choose "Connect".